# assets folder is not reachable in cordova / ember.js project

Tags: windows, cordova, ember.js, directory, assets

I am developing an app for my windows phone 10, using ember.js and cordova. I am unable to display images - always getting the following error:

> The app couldn’t resolve
>   ms-appx://io.cordova.myappXXXX/assets/images/myImage.png because of
>   this error: DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE.

My workflow:

1. creating ember.js app
2. folder for images:

   > myEmberProject/public/assets/images/myImage.png
3. Image-HTML tag within a template:

   > < img src="{{rootURL}}assets/images/myImage.png" alt="Image not available"/>
   >
   > // {{rootURL}} = ''
4. Running this app in a browser (firefox, chrome etc.) works great for me, so next step...
5. run 'ember build'
6. copy all folders/files from

   > dist/

   to

   > myCordovaProjekt/www/
7. Debug / Run Cordova directly to my windows phone
8. App is opening, js and css files are ok, but i get no image, only the alternative text

   > Image not available

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: `{{rootURL}}` - usually this would be /  .  if not you can try using `< img src="/assets/images/myImage.png" alt="Image not available"/>`

Comment: Use relative paths to your image; that should work. So `./images/myImage.png`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but it doesnt work. Any other ideas?